# SonarQube Cxx plugin: Unable to parse file

Tags: c++, sonarqube, static-analysis

Yesterday I upgraded SonarQube to Version 5.6 LTS. Today I get parse errors that did not occur in version 5.5.

ERROR: Unable to parse file: C:\Agent_work\1\s\source.implementation\as\AppServerReceive\AppServerReceive.cpp

```
ERROR: Parse error at line 28 column 38:
--> BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAppServerReceiveApp, CServerApplication)
29: 
30: 
31: 
32: 
33: 
34: END_MESSAGE_MAP()
35: 
36: 
37: 
38: 
39: CAppServerReceiveApp theApp;
40: 
41: 
42: 
43: 
44: CAppServerReceiveApp::CAppServerReceiveApp()
45: : CServerApplication(m_AppServerReceiveCommandLineInfo),
46: m_CommunicationStub(*new CCommunicationStub()),
47: m_MonitoringThread
```

I have a total of 10 Parse Errors. The above is just the first one. Any idea how to resolve this? Thank you

Comment: Please contact SonarSource support if this is about the commercial C/C++ plugin

Comment: I use the C++ Community plugin version 0.95 from https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/releases.

Comment: It looks like I need Cxx plugin version 0.96 for SonarQube 5.6 LTS. See https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/SonarQube-compatibility-matrix. I probably have to revert to 5.5 until 0.96 is ready (the latest available version is still 0.95)

Comment: I just updated to version 0.96 of the SonarQube Community Cxx plugin. Unfortunately, I get the same parse errors as with 0.95. So it had nothing to do with version incompability.